# ABNewPersonViewController Address "Address" and "City" overlap

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7, addressbook

New to iOS development—taking over an existing project and trying to get all of the UI Tweaks done for iOS7.

We use contacts in our application. When users tap to Add a contact in our ContactsListManagerView.m from a UIActionSheet we instantiate a new ABNewPersonViewController:

```
ABNewPersonViewController *adder = [[ABNewPersonViewController alloc] init];
[adder setNewPersonViewDelegate:self];
```

We add a single delegate method for ABNewPersonViewController in ContactsListManagerView.m:

```
newPersonViewController:didCompleteWithNewPerson:
```

I don't really see any other references to this viewcontroller.

The problem I'm having is that when you add an address for a new person there is an "Address" field that overlaps with the "City" field. See screenshot here: http://cl.ly/image/0h3I0L3K3K1G

I'm not sure where this field is coming from, or what properties are available to even make this kind of change. Any help you all can provide would be much appreciated.